# Custom View: Tell children that parent has another size

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view (ViewGroup) which will get animated from width = 0dp to width = 300dp.
I want to manipulate the canvas after it's children were drawn. To achive this I am overriding dispatchDraw(Canvas). 
However, I want the children to get rendered on a 300dp canvas - even when the custom view's size is less. 
When passing a larger canvas to the dispatchDraw(Canvas) method the children don't adjust their position and size.

My question, how can I "fake" a bigger width of my viewgroup so that the children get rendered on a bigger surface?

Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time a view (including ViewGroups) needs to draw itself the onMeasure method is called in order to get its dimensions. After that the onLayout is called in order to get the position on where will draw. This is not happen in the draw methods since they are called after onMeasure and onLayout see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#custom). Summing up the onMeasure calculates the dimensions, the onLayout set the positions and finally onDraw do the rendering. So your best bet is to use onMeasure to set your desired dimensions. For example this is an onMeasure method which will tell to a child view that its dimensions should be exactly 300 x 150 pixels:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int widthSpec;
    int heightSpec;

    widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(300, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(150, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    llTopBar.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec); //<-- llTopBar is the child...

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec); //<--This is important
}
```

If you want to use dips instead of pixels you have to convert them see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels).

You can measure a children with dimensions bigger than the available space but the results may not be what you expect because of clipping or other factors (if your ViewGroup is in another ViewGroup for example).

I can see from your question that you are building something that it slides from left to right, maybe the slidingdrawer source code will be helpful take a look [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.java#SlidingDrawer.onMeasure%28int,int%29).

Hope this helps...